# Solve polynomial equation with real parameter

Tags: polynomials

Solve the equation $x^4-(2m+1)x^3+(m-1)x^2+(2m^2+1)x+m=0,$ where $m$ is a real parameter.

My work: So far I've been able to factor the polynomial to $(-x^2+x+m)(-x^2+2mx+1)=0$. Then after using the quadratic formula with each of the factors I'm here: $x=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4m}}{-2}$  and $x=\frac{-2m \pm \sqrt{4m^2+4}}{-2}$

Comment: Okay, what more do you want?  It looks like you have solved the problem!

Comment: This is correct.. you have done a good job

Comment: Dave, do you need to determine number of real solutions? The second fraction gives always two different real solutions. In the first one, the number of solutions depends on the sign of discriminant $1+4m.$

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could establish values for m. Thank ya'll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the negatives out. It will look tidier.
So:
$$(x^2-x-m)(x^2-2mx-1)=0$$
Then:
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4m}}{2}=\frac 12\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-4m}}{2}$$
And:
$$x=\frac{2m\pm\sqrt{4m^2+4}}{2}=m\pm\sqrt{m^2+1}$$
You can't do anything more here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not sure if they are all roots. The fundamental theorem of algebra implies that a polynomial of positive degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots. In your case, there should be 4 roots and you have found them.